# JMX results are confusing

Tags: java, jvm, cpu-usage, jvm-hotspot, jvm-languages

I am trying to learn JMX for the last few days and now got confuse here.

1. I have written a simple JMX programe which is using the APIs of package java.lang.management and trying to extract the Pid, CPU time, user time. In my result I am only getting the results of current JVM thread which is my JMX programe itself but I thought I should get the result of all the processes running over JVM on the same machine. How I will get the pids, cpu time, user time for all java processes running in JVM(LINUX/WDs).
2. How should I can get the pids, cpu time, user time for all non-java processes running in my machine(LINUX/WDs).

My code is below:

```
public void update() throws Exception{
    final ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    final long[] ids = bean.getAllThreadIds();
    final ThreadInfo[] infos = bean.getThreadInfo(ids);
    for (long id : ids) {
        if (id == threadId) {
            continue;   // Exclude polling thread
        }
        final long c = bean.getThreadCpuTime(id);
        final long u = bean.getThreadUserTime(id);
        if (c == -1 || u == -1) {
            continue;   // Thread died
        }
    }
    String name = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
        name = infos[i].getThreadName();
        System.out.print("The name of the id is /n" + name);
    }
}
```

I am always getting the result:

> The name of the id is Attach Listener
>   The name of the id is Signal Dispatcher
>   The name of the id is Finalizer
>   The name of the id is Reference Handler
>   The name of the id is main

I have some other java processes running on my machine they are not been included in the results of bean.getAllThreadIds() API..

Comment: Please post relevant sections of the code you are using to call into the JMX APIs.

Comment: Could it be that you are confusing JVM processes and threads inside a JVM? Your code goes through the threads of the executing JVM, but in your question you are saying "all java processes".

Comment: Sorry, my apology for using JVM processes and threads terms interchangeably.
1.Running single JVM.
2.Running couple of java programs having true in while condition.
3.At the same time, running above JMX program to know the CPU utilization and user time. 
4.I assumed that JMX program should give me the CPU utilization time and user time of my all java programs (of Step 2 & Step 3) but with the above code I am only getting the CPU utilization time and user time of my JMX program (Step 3)
5.I need CPU utilization time and user time for all java programs running in JVM in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I see what you want to do. I'm afraid I have some bad news.

The APIs that are exposed through `ManagementFactory` allow you to monitor only the JVM in which your code is running. To monitor other JVMs, you have to use the JMX Remoting API (`javax.management.remote`), and that introduces a whole new range of issues you have to deal with.

It sounds like what you want to do is basically write your own management console using the stock APIs provided by out-of-the-box JDK. Short answer: you can't get there from here.  Slightly longer answer: you can get there from here, but the road is long, winding, uphill (nearly) the entire way, and when you're done you will most likely wish you had gone a different route (read that: use a management console that has already been written).

I recommend you use [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or some other management console to monitor your application(s). In my experience it is usually only important that a human (not a program) interpret the stats that are provided by the various MBeans whose references are obtainable through the `ManagementFactory` static methods. After all, if a program had access to, say, the amount of CPU used by some other process, what conceivable use would it have with that information (other than to provide it in some human-readable format)?

Comment: "what conceivable use" - in these days of cloud computing I can see it being extremely useful to be able to automatically monitor the CPU load of other processes on the machine for auto-scaling purposes.  Amazon EC2 already collects these kinds of statistics at the machine level but it also lets you define your own [custom metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) that are more specific to your own application.

Comment: is that means that if I have two java application running in my system both will be running in their own JVM?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Can you please let me know then how it goes with the JMX which is used to monitor all the java and non java process running on the same machine. If JMX runs independent in his own JVM and other java programs run separately on the same machine in their own JVMs then how ManagementFactory library can be used to monitor all java and non java program running on the same machine

Comment: Can any one clear me how JMX works?I have gone through online tutorial but still not sure how JMX works, how to get all the process running on the LINUX machine, how much % these process are using system resources, time etc